# Oracle Create trigger statement fails with internal error code ORA-00600

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Trying to execute a dumpfile created from Oracle. Everything gets created and altered fine until this block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "LABS"."CHANNEL_CHANNEL_ID_TRG" BEFORE INSERT ON channel
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
v_newVal NUMBER(12) := 0;
v_incval NUMBER(12) := 0;
BEGIN
IF INSERTING AND :new.CHANNEL_ID IS NULL THEN
SELECT  channel_CHANNEL_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO v_newVal FROM DUAL;
-- If this is the first time this table have been inserted into (sequence == 1)
IF v_newVal = 1 THEN 
  --get the max indentity value from the table
  SELECT NVL(max(CHANNEL_ID),0) INTO v_newVal FROM channel;
  v_newVal := v_newVal + 1;
  --set the sequence to that value
  LOOP
       EXIT WHEN v_incval>=v_newVal;
       SELECT channel_CHANNEL_ID_SEQ.nextval INTO v_incval FROM dual;
  END LOOP;
END IF;
--used to emulate LAST_INSERT_ID()
--mysql_utilities.identity := v_newVal; 
-- assign the value from the sequence to emulate the identity column
:new.CHANNEL_ID := v_newVal;
END IF;
END;
```

This fails and severs the connection, giving the following rather cryptic error:

```
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kqlidchg1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_PLSCOPE_SIG_IDENTIFIER$) violated
00603. 00000 -  "ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error"
*Cause:    An ORACLE server session is in an unrecoverable state.
*Action:   Login to ORACLE again so a new server session will be create
```

Comment: http://www.db-eccentric.com/2011/04/ora-0600-type-of-day.html

Comment: `ORA-00600` indicates an oracle bug, in this case seemingly an interaction between import and PL/Scope. In this case your workaround (turn off PL/Scope) is fine. If you need to use PL/Scope, you can re-enable it and recompile the trigger.

Answer (score 9):

Found a solution that worked.  Surround the block of code with the following ALTER statements:

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS = 'IDENTIFIERS:NONE';
```

... sql statements here ...

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS = 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL';
```

For some reason, the Oracle database dump does not include these commands, but this fixed the problem.